# Is there a way to set a <div> wrapper around a webform without customizing the webform?

Tags: webforms

I would like to add a `<div>` wrapper around a webform. Is there a way to define the wrapper without customizing the webform?

Answer (score 3):

You do this via the YAML source

```
'#prefix': '<div class="custom-wrapper">'
'#suffix': '</div>'
textfield:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': textfield
```

I did find a bug that I created a [ticket for in the Webform issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3223777) and posted a patch.  I recommend using the above approach with the [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-07-15/3223777-2.patch).

Comment: Bug seems gone (6.2).

You can edit it from UI page:  edit the element >  Advanced tab > Custom settings > Custom properties

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell what you mean by "without customizing the webform", but if you mean "without editing the webform configuration of each webform," then you can theme webforms like any other entity in Drupal.

If you check the `webform/templates` directory, you will see the file `webform.html.twig`.  You can copy this file into your site's theme `templates` directory and add the `<div>` wrapper in this file.

After you rebuild the site's cache, all webforms will now have the `<div>` wrapper that you added to `webform.html.twig`.